# Need Help in my website IP Canonicalization .htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect, ip, canonicalization

i have searched the whole internet to find solution my website is www.hrxlevels.tk and ip address associated with website is this 31.170.163.33 and want the .htaccess for ip to redirect to domain

```
# Do not remove this line, otherwise mod_rewrite rules will stop working
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^hrxlevels.tk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.hrxlevels.tk/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^31\.170\.163\.33
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.hrxlevels.tk/$1 [L,R=301

RewriteBase /
```

and this code is not working for ip canonicalization but works great for url cononicalization please help please!
please use this detail and please write the .htaccess file for my website.

My webhost is 000webhost.com